# How to allow .bin files upload?

Tags: uploads, media-library, customization

How can I allow .bin files upload in media library?

I have found couple codes online but none of them actually work.

Comment: Have you tried [WP Extra File Types](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-extra-file-types/)? It comes highly recommended and appears to be actively developed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code would allow you to upload `.bin` files.

```
/**
 * Allow upload bin mime type
 */
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'wpse_287673_allow_upload_bin_mime_type', 1, 1 );

function wpse_287673_allow_upload_bin_mime_type( $mime_types ) {

  $mime_types['bin'] = 'application/octet-stream';

  return $mime_types;
}
```

This code is tested and is working for me, but it might be some differences for you since we are allowing files to be uploaded by extension and mime type and mime type of your file is defined by webserver.

Comment: Thanks for the code, it works. I've used similar code that I've found online but it didn't work, but your does :). Thanks a bunch!